# Получить и записать в div данные из json в созданный createTextNode без jQuery

Tags: javascript, json

Как получить и записать в div данные из json в созданный createTextNode без jQuery?
Логика должна быть такая, получаем данные из json, разбираем их по параметрам и записываем каждый параметр в создаваемый createTextNode и добавляем каждый поочереди.

Вот мой совсем примерный код:

```
<div id="contacts_list"></div>

var module_contacts_list = (function () {
    function ajax(url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            //if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                if (this.status == 200)
                    callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
            }
        };
        xhr.send(null);
    }
    ajax('http://demo.sibers.com/users', function (data) {
        var div_contact = document.createElement('div'),
            contact_info = document.createTextNode('json данные');//как сюда записать массив данных из json?
        div_contact.className = 'contact';
        var contact_name = data.map(function (el) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('.contact').append(el.name);
            }
        });
        var contact_email = data.map(function (el) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('.contact').append(el.email);
            }
        });
        document.getElementById('contacts_list').appendChild(div_contact);
        div_contact.appendChild(contact_name);
        div_contact.appendChild(contact_email);
    });
})();
```

Уточняю вопрос: как вывести не все данные из json, а только по отдельным атрибутам - имя, почта, аватарка и т.д

Comment: уточнила вопрос

Comment: Нужно посмотреть ваш получаемый `json`.  Возможно, банально `data.text`.

Comment: пробую вот так  https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/cpu2fahL/2/ Пытаюсь вывести по имени , выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Anna Conroy' of undefined
Но хотя бы уже читает json

Comment: Вы что-то много лишних действий делаете. Вам всего лишь надо в цикле пробежаться по `data` и на основе каждой итерации создавать новый элемент `contact` в него добавлять данные, как вам надо и добавлять в родителя... остальные циклы вообще излишни.... вот посмотрите. вам примерно так надо? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWzoBK

Comment: `data.map` уже бежит по массиву, нет смысла внутри передаваемой функции бежать по нему же еще раз

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, почему не ответом? :-)

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, `data.attribute` - _undefiend_ потому что `data` это массив, а у массива нет свойства `attribute`

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, добавьте в вопрос пример html, который вы в итоге хотите получить.

Comment: да, вид примерно такой должен быть. только без текста `json данные`. спасибо большое! буду дальше разбираться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы совершаете много лишних действий.

`map` -  создаёт новый массив с результатом вызова указанной функции для каждого элемента массива. Т.е уже бежит по массиву. Внутри него нет смысла делать еще циклы.

Вам всего лишь надо в цикле пробежаться по `data` и на основе каждой итерации создавать новый элемент `contact`, в него добавлять данные, как вам надо и добавлять в родителя. Остальные циклы вообще излишни. Вот пример:

```js
var module_contacts_list = (function () {
    function ajax(url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            //if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                if (this.status == 200)
                    callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
            }
        };
        xhr.send(null);
    }
  
    ajax('http://demo.sibers.com/users', function (data) {
        var list = document.getElementById('contacts_list');

        data.map(function (el) {        
          var div_contact = document.createElement('div');
          div_contact.className = 'contact';

          var contact_info = document.createTextNode('json данные:');
          
          var contact_name = document.createTextNode('Имя:' + el.name);
          var contact_email = document.createTextNode('Email:' + el.email);
          div_contact.appendChild(contact_info);  
          div_contact.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
          div_contact.appendChild(contact_name);  
          div_contact.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
          div_contact.appendChild(contact_email);  
          div_contact.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
          var img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = el.avatar;
          div_contact.appendChild(img);
          list.appendChild(div_contact);   
      }); 
    });
})();
```

```css
.contact{
    clear:both;
    border:1px solid #F62459;
    margin:5px 0;
    padding:10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
 }
.contact img{
    float:left;
    margin-right:15px;
    max-height: 100px;
    width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="contacts_list"></div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWzoBK

На основе примера, конечно можно вытащить и остальные данные и расположить их так как вы хотите, со всеми остальными элементами и узлами.

**P.S.** Как правильно отметил @Grundy:  в данном случае лучше использовать `forEach`, так как `map` используется, если мы хочем вернуть результат выполнения callback функции:

```
var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
var roots = numbers.map(Math.sqrt);
// теперь roots равен [1, 2, 3], а numbers всё ещё равен [1, 4, 9]
```

А в вашем случае мы только обрабатываем полученные данные, не более.

Comment: а почему в одном случае `p` добавляется пустой, а в других `br`? :-) кстати, в данном случае лучше `forEach` использовать, так как мы не используем нигде массив который `map` возвращает

Comment: `forEach` вместо `map` ?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, да

Comment: а еще вопрос, надо было сделать модулем. я правильно это реализовала? `var module_contacts_list = (function () {...}`

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, нет - если посмотрите значение `module_contacts_list` увидите что оно _undefined_, потому что вы ничего не возвращаете из вызываемой функции. Таким образом присвоение можно опустить. И вместо модуля получилась просто самовызываемая функция

Comment: @Grundy то `p` то `br` потому, что я не знаю точно, какую структуру нужно автору. Просто для примера сделал. Чтоб не сливалось. И пару раз даже написал, что расположить надо так, как хочет ТС. А внутри цикла можно творить, что душе угодно...по поводу `foeEach` согласен =)

Comment: даже не знаю, отдельный вопрос задавать или здесь же... 
что необходимо добавить чтобы это был модуль ? я на этом примере делала http://forwebdev.ru/javascript/module-pattern/ 
судя по всему что-то упускаю...

Comment: @MarinaVoronova вот это:  `return {
    // публичные методы` вы видите что-то похоже в вашем примере?

Comment: и еще вопрос, чтобы записать каждый атрибут в отдельный элемент, например `span` или `p` нужен цикл `for` ? его для каждой переменной `contact_name`, `contact_email` и т.д. писать ?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova: возможно, об этом стоит задать отдельный вопрос )

Comment: Вот вам [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34904/discussion-on-answer-by-------div---js), чтобы обсудить детали.